# SwiftUI custom TextField with focus ring on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, textfield, textfieldstyle

I want to have my custom TextField style on macOS, that also has the focus ring

however i am running into 2 issues, depending if i use `.textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)` or `.textFieldStyle(.plain)`

```
struct FTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {
    func _body(configuration: TextField<Self._Label>) -> some View {
        configuration
            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding(6)
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            .background(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(6)
            .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.25), radius: 2, x: 0, y: 0.5)
            .focusable()
    }
}

TextField("E-mail", text: $email).textFieldStyle(FTextFieldStyle())
```

## When using .roundedBorder

1. the focus ring is misalligned
2. the "bezel" cannot be removed

[image]

## When using .plain

- i cannot restore the focus ring functionality, even by adding .focusable(), the focus ring is gone

[image]

**So how to have a custom TextField that has the system focus ring?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a custom focus ring using `@FocusState` & `.overlay`:

```
struct FTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {
    @FocusState var isFocused: Bool
    func _body(configuration: TextField<Self._Label>) -> some View {
        configuration
            .textFieldStyle(.plain)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding(6)
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            .background(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(6)
            .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.25), radius: 2, x: 0, y: 0.5)
            .focusable()
            .focused($isFocused)
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6).stroke(Color.accentColor.opacity(0.5), lineWidth: 4).opacity(isFocused ? 1 : 0).scaleEffect(isFocused ? 1 : 1.04))
            .animation(isFocused ? .easeIn(duration: 0.2) : .easeOut(duration: 0.0), value: isFocused)
    }
}
```

Comment: how to also get the animation?

Comment: add `.animation(.easeIn(duration: 0.2), value: isFocused)`

Comment: this creates the default fadeIn animation but when you want to come closer to the system animation with focus ring scale and opacity?

Comment: It is pretty close

Comment: edited your answer and added the scale

Comment: Could you please accept my answer if it was of any help? Thanks, have a great day!

Comment: yes, i am waiting if there wont an other answer, which is not based on faking the system focus... but for now i am using this one